# Accidentally killed SteamService.exe under wininit (Process explorer)

Tags: windows-7, steam, process-explorer

I rebooted my computer and checked on process explorer to see if it had returned. But it was gone.

What is SteamService.exe exactly? And why has it not come back after I killed the process under wininit?

Is it important?

How do I restore it? Do I need to?

Comment: Do you use Steam or have steam account in your PC? http://store.steampowered.com/ - If you do, then that is what SteamService came from. About whether you need to restore or not, if you can't run Steam games, then that answers your question.

Comment: Yes, I use steam. I can still run games, but I suspect it might cause some issues in the future.
Any way I can restore it?

Comment: Just opening up Steam should restart SteamService. If it is not causing you any issues, then most likely no need to worry about it. You only killed the process right? Then most likely a restart will start all those again.

Comment: Hm, I restarted steam but still it wasn't on the process list...

Answer (score 0):

SteamService.exe is used for a gaming client by the name of Steam, to start this exact process open Windows Task Manager and while in processes click file, then New Task (Run...) and type SteamService.exe and click okay.

Now this should start right back up after relaunching Steam.

If you want this to start when Windows boots up you can click on your start menu and type "msconfig" and press enter, navigate to start up and and make sure Steam is ticked.